# c++ how to pass two arrays to a function and return them both?

Tags: c++, arrays, return, sudoku, solver

I have two arrays:

```
      int sudoku[9][9];
      bool possiblevalues[81][9];
```

I want to initialize them both. I pass them to a function initialize (sudoku, possiblevalues). This one initializes the arrays and returns them. Now is my question: how do I return them properly? Because it won't let me use pointers or references.

Comment: Um... wut? Won't let you use pointers?

Comment: Are you having compilation issues?

Comment: use vectors instead since it's c++

Comment: If you can't use pointers or references, you would have to use to different functions. You can't return two different arrays in one function.

Comment: use `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` & `std::vector<std::vector<bool> >`.

Comment: I'd still like to know what is meant by "it won't let me use pointers or references." What won't let you? The compiler? The language? Are we all on the same page here?

Comment: I got it now ... simple use of brackets can do miracles :d

Comment: @OGH You can't return (C style) arrays from a function, period.

Answer (score 1):

Take the arrays by reference, then you don't need to return them:

```
void initialize(int (&sudoku)[9][9], bool (&possiblevalues)[81][9])
{
    // code to initialize here.
    // Any changes you make here will be reflected to the arrays
    // that have been passed to the function
}
```

Using raw arrays like this isn't particulary "good" C++. I suggest you learn how to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).